# Generating scatterplots from tables in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot the number of occurrences in `a` against the number of occurrences in `b`. The start is straightforward:

```
> a <- c(1,2,3,2,2,3,3,2,3)
> b <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,3,2,1)
> table(a)
a
1 2 3 
1 4 4 
> table(b)
b
1 2 3 
3 3 3
```

How do I generate the final plot?

```
> plot(table(a), table(b))
Error in plot.xy(xy, type, ...) : invalid plot type
```

doesn't work. What I'm looking for is a scatterplot with three points: (1,3), (4,3), and (4,3). So the horizontal axis should give you the number of occurrences in `a`, while the vertical axis should give you the number of occurrences in `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
plot(x = as.numeric(table(a)), y = as.numeric(table(b)))
```

two of your points have the same coordinates, so it appears on the `plot` that there are only two points

In the case where you have different lengths for `a` and `b`, you can first convert both to a `factor` and explicitly specify the levels:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,2,2,3,3,2,3,0,4)
b <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,3,2,1)

a = factor(a, levels = 0:4)
b = factor(b, levels = 0:4)

# > table(a)
# a
# 0 1 2 3 4 
# 1 1 4 4 1 
# > table(b)
# b
# 0 1 2 3 4 
# 0 3 3 3 0

plot(x = as.numeric(table(a)), y = as.numeric(table(b)))
```

Comment: This is a great and simple answer. However it doesn't work if `a <- c(1,2,3,2,2,3,3,2,3,0,4)`, because the `'x' and 'y' lengths differ`. Can the solution be generalized?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
list(a, b)  %>% 
    map(table) %>% 
    map(as.data.frame) %>% 
    reduce(full_join, by = 'Var1') %>%
    rename(a = Freq.x, b = Freq.y) %>%
    ggplot(., aes(a, b )) +
        geom_point(shape = 19, size = 5) +
        theme_minimal()
```

[image]